# How to add string in one column based on string avaliable on another column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have 2 column in excel. 
Suppose F column has values as 
abc , cde
agh, cde
ghl, cde
gjh
dhjf, sklad

and column H has some string like
ad , dh
bc , ds
csd
fds
dsf

My question is, how can add a string "abhi" in respective row of H,  if the respective row of F finds a string "cde".

for example if F1 has cde string then add string "abhi" in H1 row.

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. Do you want to set `abhi` in **every** cell of the F column? Show us a screenshot or a file...

Comment: Sorry.. My question is .. For every cell in F column having cde, add a word "abhi" in the respective cell of H column..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easy solution using formula but an extra column:

In column J (start at cell `J1`), use this formula:

```
=H1 & IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("cde",F1))), "abhi", "")
```